# WPF C# Get Root Node of TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView that is binded through a HierarchicalDataTemplate

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="HierachrTree" DataType="{x:Type src:Ordner}" ItemsSource="{Binding UnterOrdner}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding OrdnerName}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Thats my TreeView:

```
<TreeView Name="DokumentBrowser" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource HierachrTree}"
```

Now I want to get the first node and set the IsExpanded Property to false.

I tried it this way

```
        ItemCollection ic = DokumentBrowser.Items;
        TreeViewItem tvi = (TreeViewItem)ic.GetItemAt(0);
        tvi.IsExpanded = false;
```

but i can't cast the Object back to a TreeViewItem to get the IsExpanded Property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TreeView.Items` is a collection of the data objects, not of the TreeViewItems.  You can use the [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) to get the mapping from data objects to the TreeViewItems that are the containers.

```
TreeViewItem tvi =
    (TreeViewItem) DokumentBrowser.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
```

If you start with a data object instead of the index then you can use ContainerFromItem:

```
TreeViewItem tvi =
    (TreeViewItem) DokumentBrowser.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(
        DokumentBrowser.Items.GetItemAt(0));
```