# How do I retrieve the objects with which a WPF Treeview was populated?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview

I have a treeview bound to simple Nodes, each containing two strings (Expression, Exp2) and a list of Nodes (Children).
I also made it so that when a particular textbox is double-clicked, it raises an event that gives me a TreeViewItem.

How do I get from there to the Node from which the TreeViewItem was made?

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,80,20,20">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Node}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Expression}"/>
                    <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding Exp2}"/>-->
                </Grid>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

    </TreeView>


private void TreeViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if(sender is TreeViewItem)
        {
            if (!((TreeViewItem)sender).IsSelected)
            {
                return;
            }
            TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
            //???
            //Profit
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you referring to the node's Parent node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF C# Get Root Node of TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514043/wpf-c-sharp-get-root-node-of-treeview)

Comment: You could store a reference to the Node in the `Tag` property of the TreeViewItem, but can you access TreeViewItem.DataContext directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is complicated.

1. Get the TreeViewItem's parent (as an `ItemsControl`)

   ```
   var parent = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
   ```
2. Then use the parent's `ItemContainerGenerator` to get the data like this:

   ```
   var node = parent?.ItemContainerGenerator?.ItemFromContainer(item);
   ```

Comment: For WPF, this doesn't really seem all that complicated.

Comment: For me and you - maybe not, but for a lot of people needing this kind of help, then most probably